# Enable mouse for scrolling only in Vim in iTerm (MacOSX)

Tags: macos, vim, mouse, scrolling, iterm

I'd like to use the mouse in Vim *only* for scrolling (not to enable other Vim modes or otherwise interact with Vim).  Using `:set mouse=a` seems to be an all or nothing operation, can this be altered?  Alternatively can iTerm be made to only pass through scroll events and never click/drag events?

Long Explanation: I use Vim in iTerm a lot and don't use the mouse.  However, inertia scrolling with a trackpad is really nice and a great way to peruse large files.  I can `:set mouse=a` and use the trackpad to scroll and it's great.  Now when I click however vim enters visual mode and iTerm will not copy selected text.  I would like to retain iTerms ability to select and copy text.

I have thought about setting up Vim so that copying in vim will copy in Mac OS X (using pbcopy, I need to do this anyway).  This will do the trick when editing local files, but most of the time I'm `ssh`'d somewhere and editing remote files.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use

```
:set mouse=nicr
```

It works only with mouse scroll as I've tested.

Comment: Not quite what I need as while it will scroll in vim, iTerm won't let me select text.  I've `:set mouse=i` so that scroll works in insert mode and iTerm select in normal mode.  Close enough, so I'm marking answered.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: That looks like "set the mouse to be nicer" to me.

Comment: @JonahBraun, iTerm will mouse select with `:set mouse=nicr` if you hold down option while making the selection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608161/copy-text-out-of-vim-with-set-mouse-a-enabled

Comment: Where do you write `:set mouse=nicr`?

Comment: You can either write that every single time you start Vim, or you could write that in the file `~/.vimrc`, but consider also `:set mouse=a`, as @MikeMorearty suggests below. This makes selection of text possible, too. (It goes into visual mode, which some may not like.)

Answer (score 25):

If you `set mouse=a`, you can still use **Option**-click to make iTerm do selection.  Not ideal, but it's the best option I've found.

Comment: this is the real workable answer.

Comment: It certainly is.

Answer (score 20):

### For Iterm2

Preference -> Advanced -> Mouse Tab, switch:

```
Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode
```

to:

```
Yes
```

Comment: Enter vim > mouse wheel scrolls within vim only. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: In my case you must set this iTerm config AND hold down `Option` when scrolling with the trackpad/the mouse wheel.

Comment: ba dum tss ! worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about iTerm but this is achievable with Terminal.app.

- Scrolling in Terminal.app:

http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/using-mouse-inside-vim-on-terminal-app/
(install SIMBL and MouseTerm)

- Scrolling only:

  1. Go to terminal;
  2. Preference;
  3. 'Settings' Icon;
  4. 'Keyboard' Tab
  5. 'Mouse...' button;
  6. There under 'Send mouse events for:" uncheck "Left click", "Middle click", "Right click".

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set vim env [options from command line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/setting-a-vim-option-from-the-command-line)

For example:

```
vim -c 'set mouse=a'
```

So an alternate alias for vim that does it automatically might be:

```
alias vimmy="vim -c 'set mouse=a'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Even better than the accepted answer:

```
set mouse=a
```

This allows scrolling and then highlighting gives you a visual block.

Comment: This enables things other than scrolling.

Comment: Moreover, that is already mentioned in the question.